# Visual Studio 2010 - How to get TFS options to show in toolbar and window tab context menu

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

This is to do with setting up my Visual Studio to do TFS workflows in a convenient manner. Currently I have to lookup the code file, seek it in my Solution Explorer and then right click on that file to see the Source Control Options. I am aware there is the option to right click within the source and select Source Control, but I would like to enable more options.

What I would like to do is right-click on the code window tab, and for the Source Control options to show up. This was how I worked with SVN and AnkhSVN plugin for VS. The specific items I would like to see is 'View History' and 'Annotate'.

Another thing I noticed in my toolbar, I have setup the Source Control - Team Foundation options, and I have checkin, checkout, View History, but I can't get Annotate to show up as an option. I can't believe MS would have skipped on this option, there must be something I'm doing wrong.

If anyone knows how I can enable the TFS Source Control context menus on the code tab, or how to add Annotate on the toolbar menu, that would be great.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options to view history and see an annotated view of the file is available from the right click menu in the editor.  Does that satisfy your needs, or are the reasons for specifically wanting it on the tab?

Here's how to add the Annotate button to the TFS source control toolbar.

1. For that toolbar, click "Add or Remove Buttons" and click "Customize...".
2. In the Customize dialog, click "Add Command...".
3. Choose "File" in the left column, and choose "TfsAnnotate" in the right column.

Buck

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Although I was hoping for a way to have this on the context menu, toolbar button is fine as well

Comment: What to do if View History and Annotate do not show up in the context menu? (Works for me, not for my teammate.)